# How to return id from django rest framework to angular application

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a http post from an angular application:

```
var body = {client: 1, quantityItem: 2, price: this.formData.GTotal, profitability: 'profitable'}
    return this.http.post(environment.apiURL+'/order/', body, {headers: this.httpHeaders});
```

I'm sending the fields from the application and the djangorestframework backend generates the id for the order, how can i get this id? so I can make another http post with the order items and the order id.

models(order):

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    quantityItem = models.BigIntegerField(default=1)
    grand_total = models.FloatField(default=0)
    profitability = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

models(orderitem):

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    quantityProduct = models.BigIntegerField(default=1)
```

serializers.py:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id', 'client', 'quantityItem', 'grand_total',
                  'profitability', 'create_date', 'update_date')
```

viewsets.py:

```
class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
```

what I have to do get the id back and send another request with the order items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 good approaches for this.

> **1-** first create order in angular then send another request with angular to create OrderItem for it

When you created the Order object with post request, in response django rest-framework by default return a serialized object that contains json of that created object. so you could easily fetch that `id` value, then after that (in callback, promise then or any other method you use) try to create a new request to create `orderItem` for that `order` id.

for example if you use promise in your angular cli, it's something like this:

```
var body = {client: 1, quantityItem: 2, price: this.formData.GTotal,  profitability: 'profitable'}
this.http.post(environment.apiURL+'/order/', body, {headers:  this.httpHeaders}).toPromise().then(data => {
    let order_id = data['id'];
    let data2 = {'order': order_id, .... other data here ...}
    this.http.get(environment.apiURL+'/orderItem/', data2 ........ // rest of code here
});
```

> **2-** create a nested serializer in django, so create all order and it's orderItems in one request.

so your json that will be send to django will be like this:

```
{'user': 1, 'client': 2, 'orderItems': [{'product': 3}, {'product': 4}],...}
```

and simply in django-rest just override `create` method of django `CreateModelMixin` like this:

```
class OrderApiView(ModelViewSet):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        orderItems = request.data.pop('orderItems', [])

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)    
        order = self.perform_create(serializer)

        for orderItem in orderItems:
            OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, product_id=orderItem['product'])
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: @K. Nathan let me know if any part of it need more details.

Comment: thank you, I only have to do some changes to adapt to my code, but this is the ideia, and worked here. Saved my day, thanks again. I used the first approach, just make sure to edit http.get to http.post for others users can use your answer.

Comment: any time my friend :)